# auto mount usb-drive when not logged in

Tags: linux, usb, mount, linux-mint

I'm running linux mint 17 and when I plug in a flash drive while logged in it automounts and all is good.

But if the screen is locked or if i'm not logged in it does not automount.  The problem is I have a use case where I actually want the usb drive to auto mount and be readable to all users (or just me is okay too) as soon as it's plugged in regardless of weather or not a user is logged in.

Can I configure my system to always automount?